# LayoutTransform Custom Style wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

I'm trying to set up a custom style to rotate a separator.

This code works, but is not custom style:

```
 <Separator>
    <Separator.LayoutTransform>
       <RotateTransform Angle="90" />
    </Separator.LayoutTransform>
 </Separator>
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
<Style x:Key="CustomStandaloneSeparatorStyle" TargetType="Separator">
            <Setter TargetName="LayoutTransformProperty" Property="RotateTransform.Angle" Value="{Binding ToolbarTrayElementRotation}" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2"/>
</Style>
```

The error message is: "LayoutTransformProperty is not recognized". However, it IS available as an option when tab completing that entry... Weird.

Comment: `TargetName` is for setting a property of another element, identified by its name. The error is telling you that you don't have a `<RotateTransform Name="LayoutTransformProperty">` anywhere in your window/UserControl.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. However, it doesn't really answer the question of how to do this properly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be setting the `LayoutTransform` property to an instance of `RotateTransform`:

```
<Style x:Key="CustomStandaloneSeparatorStyle" TargetType="Separator">
    <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
        <Setter.Value>
            <RotateTransform Angle="90" />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: This is exactly it other than the `Angle="{Binding ToolbarTrayElementRotation}`. Thanks! I'll accept the answer in a few minutes when it lets me.

Comment: You didn't have that in your original "working" code, so I didn't include it in my answer. :-)

Comment: Should I references these as static or dynamic resources? They both work, is there a more correct one?

Comment: That's a separate question, but the usual advice is to use StaticResource unless you need the extra overhead of DynamicResource (and it's uncommon to need DynamicResource unless you're using it for something like SystemColors that could change while your app is running).

Answer (score 1):

The property is called LayoutTransform:

```
<Style x:Key="CustomStandaloneSeparatorStyle" TargetType="Separator">
    <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
        <Setter.Value>
            <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding ToolbarTrayElementRotation}" />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2"/>
</Style>
```